# Don't want to archive messages

Tags: gmail

How do I keep an email I have answered in my inbox?  Gmail automatically sends it to *All Mail* once it has been answered.

Comment: Do you have two buttons available to you when sending the emails, one with "Send and Archive" and the other with "Send"?

Comment: _All Mail_ is the place where you find all your mail regardless of the labels applied to individual messages, so whether you have it in _Inbox_ or you archived it, it will be in _All Mail_.

Answer (score 4):

You might be using the “Send & Archive” option.

Note the difference between the two *Send* buttons:

- Send & Archive

[image]

- Send without archive

[image]

If that’s the case, go to *Settings* and search for the **Send and Archive** option. Now click on the **Hide “Send & Archive” button in reply**.

[image]